# Enabling Swing Menus on OSX with Java7

Tags: java, macos, swing, java-7, jmenu

I have a swing application in which I need to enable a JMenu from a different thread.  I'm doing this on OSX and am using the native screen menu via apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar.  Since switching to java 7 the initially disabled menus now never become enabled and I can't figure out why. I've attached a small program which illustrates the problem.  Clicking on the Fixed > Change menu item should enable the test menu after a brief pause (a dialog should open and close).

Using java6 it works fine.  In java 7 the menu is not enabled.  If I don't use the screen menu it works in 6 or 7, and if I use EventQueue.invokeAndWait it works in 6 or 7, but I don't think I should need to do this.

Is this a bug, or am I mis understanding how interactions between swing threads should work?

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class MainWindow extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JMenu testMenu;

    public MainWindow () {

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setTitle("Menu Enable Test");

        JMenuBar bar = new JMenuBar();

        JMenu fixedMenu = new JMenu("Fixed");
        JMenuItem change = new JMenuItem("Change");
        change.addActionListener(this);
        fixedMenu.add(change);
        bar.add(fixedMenu);

        testMenu = new JMenu("Test");
        testMenu.setEnabled(false);
        JMenuItem seeMe = new JMenuItem("Can you see me?");
        testMenu.add(seeMe);

        bar.add(testMenu);

        setJMenuBar(bar);

        setSize(800,600);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public void makeVisible () {
        testMenu.setEnabled(true);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        new RemoteChanger(this);
    }

    private class RemoteChanger extends JDialog implements Runnable {
        private MainWindow window;

        public RemoteChanger (MainWindow window) {
            super(window);
            setSize(200,100);
            setLocationRelativeTo(window);
            this.window = window;
            setVisible(true);
            Thread t = new Thread(this);
            t.start();
        }

        public void run() {
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {}

            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    window.makeVisible();                   
                }
            });

            setVisible(false);

        }
    }

    public static void main (String [] args) {
        System.setProperty("apple.laf.useScreenMenuBar", "true");
        new MainWindow();
    }

}
```

Comment: Don't know the answer to your question (am on Windows that does not display the problem), but +1 for posting an SSCCE.

Comment: It works fine on Ubuntu. In any case, The `MainWindow` instance should be made on the Event Dispatch Thread, since it extends a swing component.

Comment: The `new MainWindow()` line in the `main` method also needs to be inside an `EventQueue.invokeLater`.  I don't know if that will resolve the problem, though.

Comment: I tried putting the MainWindow() call inside an invokeLater call, but the problem still persists as before.

Answer (score 0):

I think the source of the issue is your `setVisible(false)` being outside of the Swing thread.  Moving it inside of the `invokeLater()` call seems more correct and gives you the expected behavior.

```
EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        window.makeVisible();    
        setVisible(false);
    }
});
```

Comment: true could be usage of Thread.sleep(int) instead of Swing Timer

Comment: This still fails if the setVisible(false) goes before the window.makeVisible().  I'm coming to the conclusion that this is a bug in the menu switching code in the OSX LAF when using the screen menu bar.